# Worldbuilding Podcast #03 - Technology and Ewoks

Tags: discussion, podcast

**[Episode 3 is up!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCSM70JKo0w)**

Thanks to Green, Nex and Art (Double thanks to Art since he does all the technical stuff) for making the podcast possible.

- In this episode we dream about what we would do with magic...but with science.
- Then we discuss a fascinating world brought to you by:

  [image]
- After that conversation we went through a few all star questions from the site and wrapped things up with recommendations for the world builders out there.

Check it out and let us know what you think.

---

Episode 3 of The Factory Floor, a podcast about building worlds and filling them with interesting things.

In this episode we introduce a new guest and co-host who happens to also be the technical magician that makes the podcast possible.

Welcome and introducing ArtOfCode:  00:00:00 – 00:09:00

Technology and Magic from the world of Green:  00:09:01 – 00:43:20

Questions from the site:  00:43:21 – 01:35:00

- [What would it take to build a ship capable of crossing the Pacific?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25272/what-would-it-take-to-build-a-ship-capable-of-crossing-the-pacific/25276#25276)
- [In what war would one modern military vehicle make a difference?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12219/in-what-war-would-one-modern-military-vehicle-make-a-difference)
- [What good are herbivores in an animal army?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/25724/what-good-are-herbivores-in-an-animal-army)
- [Truth Stone: Effects on the justice system, and criminal world](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/62572/truth-stone-effects-on-the-justice-system-and-criminal-world)

Recommendations:  01:27:01 – 01:35:14

- [Writers Complete Fantasy Reference](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1582970262)
- [Pegasus Bridge](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671671561)
- [5th Edition Dungeon Masters Guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786965622)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thanks Monica :)

Comment: Is the image supposed to be just a green field?

Comment: @Frostfyre Yep (Green presented the world)

Comment: Do you guys have any way to listen to this via iTunes podcasts?